# how to make imageview border with two color and fix size border width in andorid

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview, shapes

I have create the circularimageview and this image view set the two colors and this color sizw are same how to set border with fix size and two borders?

**I have already use library 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1' **

#ce90ce inner circle

# ab84ab outer circle

 ineer circle opacity 20%

 outer circle opacity 15%

**My Image like this**
[image]

**My Adapter Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/Background_Main"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivPerson"
    android:layout_width="77dp"
    android:layout_height="77dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:border="true"
    app:border_color="#ab84ab"
    app:border_width="10dp"
    app:shadow="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPersonName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivPerson"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/tapon"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addbn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buildlis_category_btn_selected"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:minWidth="0dp" />
```

Comment: try this<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770693/create-a-border-outside-the-circular-imageview>.

Comment: I have Already  try this but not work's size problem!!

Comment: is your image height and width are fixed

Comment: yes @ChandraSharma

Comment: try this- https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView  I think this is the simplest way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is xml code and easy to maintain :

double_circle_image.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>

        <shape android:shape="oval">

            <stroke
                android:width="10dp"
                android:color="#0000ff" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp">

        <shape android:shape="oval">

            <stroke
                android:width="10dp"
                android:color="#ff0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:bottom="20dp"
        android:left="20dp"
        android:right="20dp"
        android:top="20dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit but i have put your code but not work's for me so any other soultion? and my images are import form database not in drawable!!

Comment: in that case you need to remove below code

 <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:bottom="20dp"
        android:left="20dp"
        android:right="20dp"
        android:top="20dp"/>

and use this drawable as background

Comment: so, you can try some other tactics like take one RelativeLayout and setbackground this drawable and inside of relativeLayout take ImageView, in imageview setmargin 20dp so you can get circular effect on image

Comment: yes but i have not used imageview i have used this library  <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView/>

Comment: then use that library inside of relativelayout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124794/discussion-between-jaydeep-dhamecha-and-ronit-kadwane).

Answer (score 0):

[Use this library](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview) to shape the image to circle. You add your image using  tag, right? Then, add a background (shaded) (Vector) from drawable as well. It will enable to make the look like you wanted.

You should use vector file as your images as well. [This is cool library](http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/) to convert svg images to vector images. If you do so, your images will look like as your wished in the question, in any devices!

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: I have already  use library 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'.. I have used this library but how to set 2 types colors with same sizw?