# GridLayout border lines/visible separators?

Tags: android, gridview

I'm relatively new to android and I want to know how to put a visible divider/borders around images.

[image: Example grid menu with border/dividers]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to add an `android:background` attribute to your `ImageView` with the value of your desired border color. Then add an `android:padding` attribute to the `ImageView` with the value of your desired border width. It's not the most elegant solution, but it's understandable and for a new developer will do a fine job. For example:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/android_image"
    android:background="color/list_item_icon_border_color"
    android:padding="1dp"
    />
```

Maybe the right way for performing this is by using custom XML drawables. You could check in Google for creating borders for ImageView using custom XML drawable. However being a little more complicated way than the upper mentioned method it could be an excellent way to start with XML defined custom drawables. Sooner or later you'll have to understand it, no other way. For circular border check this post - nice and clear explanation with custom XML drawable:
[Create circular border around ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770693/create-a-border-outside-the-circular-imageview)

Answer (score 0):

In the item's layout you could put a View with heigth of 1dp or width 1dp and fill it with some color. This is a item for a list with a text and a bottom divider.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry im a newb

Comment: @JibRealNadela try now

Comment: i need borders.

Comment: the imagebutton